# Hibernate mode in UEFI on Linux

Tags: uefi, hibernate

I wanted to know how sleep and hibernate mode work on UEFI. Basically I want to know which files are created and/or edited when a Linux machine is put into hibernate mode. I read online and found out that Windows 8.1 creates a file called `hiberfil.sys`, and wanted to know if any such file is created in Linux and understand what `hiberfil.sys` actually does. Anyone with any idea please point me to the right direction.

Comment: On Linux there is a hibernation system called TuxOnIce.

Comment: K i tried tuxonice but I wanted to know if it creates a file like hiberfil.sys or some other file and if it does create it, can I access the file or read its contents

Comment: This is configurable. TuxOnIce can either suspend to swap parts/files or normal files.

Comment: Is there a link/tutorial/guide that can show me how to do it?

Comment: Try ArchWiki. Archlinux's wiki is used by users of all distros…

Comment: Thanx a ton mate got what I wanted.

Comment: Any1 have any idea as to how hiberfil.sys works in Windows?